# how to display an alert while page loading is undone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

My jsp page calls for web service and it takes some time to redirect to next page. I want to prevent user from clicking the button which calls to the web service by giving an alert to user.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are calling the web service from javascript, you can add a class to the link (e.g. 'waiting') and have the javascript only call the web service if the link doesn't have that class. Otherwise, you could write javascript to intercept the redirect and perform the check, or simply remove the href. If you show exactly what it looks like, I can elaborate more on any of these.

Comment: You could also use a click event to disable the button after it's been clicked once.

Comment: NO I cannot disable the button. The web service call is done through servlets.

Comment: You should consider accepting the answers sometimes. It gives you +2 ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create an `.overlay`

```
.overlay {
   position:absolute; 
   display:block;
   top:0; 
   left:0; 
   width:100%; 
   height:100%; 
   background:transparent;  /* or you may assign it some color or image */
   z-index:1000;
}
```

that overlays the whole page. And attach a `click` event to that `.overlay` like this:

```
$('.overlay').on('click', function(){
    alert('Please wait! Let the page be loaded first..');
});
```

And when ever the page is ready, remove the overlay.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.overlay').hide();
});
```

What this overlay would do is, prevent the user interaction to your page.

Alternative way, would be:

Not attaching the event to the button, upon which you are calling the service, prehand. And whenever the document is ready, attach the event that calls the service to the button.

Comment: Where to apply this overlay class?

Comment: @MaDu_LK just put `<div class="overlay"></div>` at the root of your body